# how to cache data in a stateful service?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

The cluster needs access to a dataset that lives in sql server, that is outside of the cluster.

Rather than forcing remote calls to the database for every request, I would like to create a stateful service that will periodically refresh its cache with data from the remote database.

Would we be looking at something like this following?

```
    internal sealed class StatefulBackendService : StatefulService
{
    public StatefulBackendService(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Optional override to create listeners (like tcp, http) for this service instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The collection of listeners.</returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new ServiceReplicaListener[]
        {
            new ServiceReplicaListener(
                serviceContext =>
                    new KestrelCommunicationListener(
                        serviceContext,
                        (url, listener) =>
                        {
                            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                            return new WebHostBuilder()
                                .UseKestrel()
                                .ConfigureServices(
                                    services => services
                                        .AddSingleton<IReliableStateManager>(this.StateManager)
                                        .AddSingleton<StatefulServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl)
                                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                .UseUrls(url)
                                .Build();
                        }))
        };
    }
}
```

Within this stateful service, how would I load data from a remote database and serve it through controllers?

Let's assume we have a simple model:

```
Create table Account (varchar name, int key)
```

I imagine that the operations would be in the following order:

1. Load Account table into memory
2. respond to requests such as http://statefulservice/account?$top=10
3. refresh data in the service on a time interval basis

**What are the datatypes that I should be using in order to cache this data? What would be the process of loading the data into the stateful service from a sql server database>?**

Comment: In one of my previous jobs we implemented such a thing using the [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.7.1) class. It's quite easy to work with.

Comment: @ZoharPeled got examples? shavua tov!

Comment: Not really, it was too long to remember. However, I'll bet [one of these is simple enough...](https://www.google.co.il/search?rlz=1C1LENP_iwIL718IL718&ei=c1r5Wb2PEsm-aICXv4AH&q=working+with+memorycache+C%23&oq=working+with+memorycache+C%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1.502385.514657.0.516136.27.24.1.0.0.0.318.3783.0j16j3j1.20.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.21.3783...0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i67k1j0i203k1j0i20i263k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i5i30k1j0i8i13i30k1j33i160k1.0.1bNlrlavFP4)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, even though it's possible to use Statefull services as a cache backed up by some database, **the real power comes when you keep your data in the reliable collections only**. With Service Fabric and Reliable Collections, you can store data directly in your service without the need for an external persistent store. See [Application scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-scenarios). Aside from providing high availability and low latency, the state is reliably replicated across multiple nodes so it could survive a node failure, and moreover, there is a [Back up and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-backup-restore) feature that allows you to deal even with the entire cluster outage.

There are many things you should know about when dealing with Reliable Services. [Service partiotioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning), [Transactions and lock modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-transactions-locks), [Guidelines and recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-guidelines), etc.

**As for the data types**, explore [Reliable Collection object serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-serialization) and [Serialization and Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-data-serialization).

Another thing you also should be aware of, is the Reliable Dictionary periodically removes least recently used values from memory, which could increase read latencies in certain cases. See more here - [Service fabric reliable dictionary linq query very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457443/azure-service-fabric-reliable-dictionary-linq-query-very-slow).

**A simple example** of integrating controllers and StateManager you could find [in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app#add-the-votedatacontrollercs-file).

Answer (score 1):

l--''''''---------''''''''''''
**Here's a little more info related to your comment...**
Hey m8...  the reliable collections are designed to run multiple instances (the run on more than one node at a time)...  Within each instance the data is partitioned into one or more groups (how you decide to partition is entirely up to you)...  So there is load distribution and fail over, there is more to say... but I don't want to muddy the waters so I'm attempting to keep it high level.  This type of service data in reliable collections exists in memory and can be "backed up"...  If you want your data formally written to disc and have more control over WHEN it is written to disc you will need to take a look at Actors.  This is a good (very simple) collection of examples of service fabric, reliable collections, and wiring up internal communications.  Only think funky about looking at this one is there are a lot of different 'recipes' used to facilitate back-end and communication from the back-end to the public (stateless) side.

I see you added to your question and changed the intent a little...  I will pointedly tell you what I 'think' you need for what you are really after...  You want one or multiple 'Stateful Service's (this is your data service layer, this can be abstracted into 3 components if you want... the stateful service itself, and 2 class libraries one for your service interface and one for your contracts ... or rather your data models... basically this is a POCO), you would include the 2 class libraries in your stateful service and use them to create dictionary entries (probably something like new IReliableDictionary... and bind the interface.  You will want to use (add to) the IService interface (you will need to grab a nuget package 'Service Fabric Remoting' for the interface project you created for your service interface, there is plenty of info out there on how to achieve remoting within service fabric as it is a standard communication method.  There is more, but simply building this would be a viable experiment and would effectively take the place or you database.  You can formally persist the data to disc using Actors or a simple backup method that is canned with service fabric.  Essentially I suggest you build this in order to firm up the fact you can completely remove the database from this scenario... you really don't need it.  What I have described above takes the place of the db ONLY... without writing a front-end for this (that uses remoting to communicate with your backend) this would not be accessible to the public... at least not easily.
TL;DR - Basically I'm agreeing with what one of your other contributors is stating... My opinion is less humble so I'll simple state it.  You application will be less complicated, faster and more reliable if you handle your data within service fabric... Still TL;DR? - Ditch the db my man. If you are really nervous about it only existing in memory, use Actors

Comment: what happens when the reliable stateful service crashes? where does the data go? how do we handle resiliency?